# Changing a sigmoid curve to have an adjustable point of inflection

Tags: special-functions, signal-processing

I am trying to an implement an adjustable [Sigmoid curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) such as in the YouTube video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RneLoH7G-kQ&app=desktop). I found a potentially good candidate:

$$f_k(x) = \frac{\left(x-x\cdot k\right)}{k-\left|x\right|\cdot 2\cdot k+1}$$

But the inflection point is always $(0,0)$.

I need an S Curve that meets the Adjustable point of inflection of Sigmoid Curve.

Especially, you can see "Input Split" and "Output Split" in YouTube as parameters. I want to add and implement these parameter into above equation for $f_k$.

So please help me with and any ideas to modify the definition of $f_k$.

Thanks.

Update : I got some comment But I'm not sure about it. and I can't understand it Does anyone know how to an implement this?
Currently I work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\Vert{#1}\bigg\Vert}
 \newcommand{\abs}  [1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\babs} [1]{\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$First, I believe you have underspecified your function.  It should be:

$$\begin{cases} f_k(x) = \frac{\left(x-x\cdot k\right)}{k-\abs{x}\cdot 2\cdot k+1} \\
-1 < x < 1 \\
0 < k < 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

This makes the domain of your function $-1 < x < 1$ and the range $-1 < f_k < 1$ (interestingly, the range doesn't depend on $k$).

For my suggestion, first shift/scale the function to make the range and domain equal to $(0 .. 1)$:

$$\begin{cases} g_k(x) = \frac{f_k(2x - 1) + 1}{2}\\
0 < x < 1 \\
0 < k < 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

This puts the inflection point of $g_k$ at $(1/2, 1/2)$.  You can now add 2 parameter $A$ and $B$ to shift the input and output:

$$\begin{cases} h_{k, A, B} (x) = g_k(\sqrt[A]{x})^B \\
0 < x < 1 \\
0 < k < 1 \\
\end{cases}$$

This puts the inflection point at $(1/2^A, 1/2^B)$.  What's left is to verify that it is still a sigmoid:

- (1) No poles in the range
- (2) Upper limit and lower limit exist
- (3) Always increasing
- (4) Only 1 point of inflection (where second derivative changes signs)

**(1)** and **(2)** don't change with the given transform.  **(3)** follows from composition of monotonic functions.  **(4)** can be verified with a bit of calculus, but intuitively since $x^z$ doesn't have an inflection point in the range of $x>0$ then it shouldn't affect the existence of inflection points when used in functional composition.

Comment: @Carter You typed the formula incorrectly.  Also add the expressions $x = 1/2^A$ and $y = 1/2^B$ after you type the formula correctly.  Also the range of $A$ and $B$ is $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: Tahnks DanielV, I got some result about your recommend. But I'm not sure about this. So Would you please check this result here? desmos.com/calculator/rekdhheffk . becasue the result is something wrong as my expectation what the curve works doesn't like YouTube. quit a bit, it looks something wrong.

Comment: @Carter Your "B" is in the wrong place.  It should be on the very outside.

Comment: @Carter Add the following: $$\begin{cases} A = \tan(C \pi / 2) \\ B = \tan(D \pi / 2) \\ C = \text{slider from 0 to 1} \\ D = \text{slider from 0 to 1} \\ x = 1/2^A \\ y = 1/2^B \end{cases}$$

Comment: Dear DanielV, If you can, would you please help me this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228409/how-can-i-get-smooth-curve-at-the-sigmoid-function?noredirect=1#comment2498367_1228409

Answer (score 1):

The function you give is the second version of my sigmoid function, which works better than the one shown in the video.

To get the effect shown, I put three NTSF in series. The first takes values from -1 to 1 converted to the range 0 to 1. The output is converted back to the range -1 to 1, and the second NTSF applied. This output is then converted to the range 0 to 1, put through a third NTSF and converted back to -1 to 1.

That is
$$\begin{align}
v_1(x) &= {\rm NTSF}\left(\frac 12 x + \frac 12 ,~ k_1\right)\cdot 2+1 \\
v_2(x) &= {\rm NTSF}\bigg(v_1(x) ,~ k_2\bigg) \\
y &= {\rm NTSF}\left(\frac 12 v_2(x) + \frac 12 ,~ k_3\right)\cdot 2+1 \\
\end{align}$$

Hope that helps

Dino

Comment: Thanks Dino. If you can Would you please let me know the NTFS function more ? I'm not sure what does "NTFS" means.

Comment: The function you show is the NTSF function taking parameters x and k