# How can I get smooth curve at the sigmoid function?

Tags: algebraic-curves, curves

I'm trying to implement the sigmoid curve by using the following function.

A is 3.2505508013 B is 1.5223545069 and K is 0.56.

## $\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\left(2\left(\sqrt[A]{xx}\right)-1\right)-\left(\left(2\left(\sqrt[A]{xxxxxxxx}\right)-1\right)\cdot k\right)\right)}{k-\left|2\left(\sqrt[A]{xxx}\right)-1\right|\cdot 2\cdot k+1}\space +1\right)}{2}\right)^B$

Then, I got the following curve.
[image]

But As you can see, in the red circle. it might be not smooth. I want to get a smooth curve like the following black curve in the red circle.
[image]

How can I get a smooth curve at the sigmoid function?

Is there any way to make smooth curve? if you have any idea, please help me.

UPDATE:
Note that a and b and c is changeable.

[image]

[image]

multiple version.
[image]

Comment: That's a remarkable expression, but can you tell us what "like this" actually means, and maybe we can provide a simpler solution? Evidently you want $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(1) = 1$, and you want $f(x) \ge x$ for all $x$. It may also be that you want $f'(1/2) = 0$, although that's not so clear from the diagram. Did I miss anything? Perhaps "$f'$ should be decreasing on $[0, 1/2]$ and increasing on $[1/2, 1]$" should be in there, too?

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution? If not then you can convolve the function with a square pulse or a gauss bell with a variance of around 0.05 to smooth out all corners.

Comment: Or how about a simpler function that looks very similar [$5x\cdot \exp(-7x)+x$](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27435112/math_weirdcurve.png)

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question very very clearly if you expect to get useful help. It would probably be helpful if you did not require that we go off and look at other websites to try to understand what you *might* be looking for. Just say it.

Comment: @JohnHughes sorry Sir, I have been updating very clearly, but please  understand me. I am just newbie about math also the question might be  seemed not clear to professors.

Comment: @DenDenDo Sir, Would you please show me how to apply above a, b, c parameter into the your equation  5x⋅exp(−7x)+x ? I need to changeable curve as a,b,c

Comment: [Desmos Demo](http://www.desmos.com/calculator/pllfzzvl08)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume the following constraints for the function $f$ from the pictue

- $f(0)=0$
- $f(1) \approx 1$
- $1<f'(0)<\infty$
- $f'(1)\approx 1$
- "hill" on $[0,b]$
- quickly goes to the asymptote on $[b,1]$

the function $x$ covers most of those points, except for the hill. So now we can write $f(x) = x + g(x)$ and need to find $g$ such that

- $g(0) = 0 \approx g(1)$
- $g'(0) >0$
- $g'(1)\approx0$
- "hill" on $[0,b]$ with height $c$ (*)

To make the hill we write g as aproduct of two functions, $g(x) = h_1(x)\cdot h_2(x)$, one with $h_1(0)=0$ and increasing, the other $h_2(0)\neq 0$ and decreasing.

One choice that allows us to tweak the parameters very simply would be $h_1 = c\cdot S(x)$ and $h_2 = \frac{1+S(b-x)}{2}$ where $S(x)$ is any sigmoidal curve with $S(\pm\infty)=\pm 1$ and $S(0)=0$, for example $S(x) = \tanh(x), S(x) = \arctan(x)\frac{2}{\pi}, S(x) = erf(x)$

Another possibility could be $h_1 = (x+1)^n-1$ and $h_2=A \exp(-kx)$ but here the relationship between $(A, n, k)$ and $(b,c)$ is not staightforward

*) if $g$ has a maximum at $(x_0, g(x_0))$ then the maximum of $f(x) = x+g(x)$ when measured orthogonally towards the diagonal is at $(x_0, x_0+g(x_0))$ and its diagonal "height" is $\frac{g(x_0)}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Thanks SIr, I think f(1) =1, and f`(1)=1 .but I can't  catch quite a bit. would you please show me at this https://www.desmos.com ?

Comment: to ensure $f(1)=f'(1)=1$ and not 1.0000001, multiply $g(x)$ with a function that is 1 almost everywhere and goes to 0 at x=1, like $\tanh(100(1-x))$. And it would really help to formalize all required function properties instead of letting us guess. Function values and derivatives, what kind of data are you trying to model, does it have to be efficient for numerical evaluation or easily to handle analytically, are piecewise functions ok? Until then you can  [play around with my examples](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2kvpkbax0f)

Comment: "Move the hill" is just as vague as before, where does the hill even end? What exactly about my answer didnt suit your purpose and what _exactly_ do you want to achieve? Right now there are more open questions on my side than on yours and randomly changing things on the chance that i might have guessed your mind is not a good way of solving things. Asking a good question is even more difficult than writing a good answer.

Comment: Sir,  at this x+((x+1)^n -1)*exp(-k*x)*m , when I set m =1 andk=3.5 andn=3.3 ,then This curve not met in f'(x)=1